# Sizing elements with each other

Tags: html, image, css

So I'm working on a sidebar which contains an image, a box below it for pagination, and some buttons below that. With just the image and the box, everything in the sidebar stayed the same `width`, adjusting with the image when it was made larger or smaller, but with the added button div below it (when the text within it gets to a certain length), the box above is being stretched in the sidebar.

[image: This is a visual of what's going on. The red is my sidebar div.]

Here's the code I have:

HTML:

```css
body {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 179px;
  left: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 120px;
}
.pages {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 2px);
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 2px);
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: -4px;
  border-left: 1px solid #E2C4FF;
  border-right: 1px solid #E2C4FF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E2C4FF;
  text-align: center;
}
.dots {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -70%);
  color: {
    color: Link Color Type 1
  }
  ;
  font-family:'Questrial',
  sans-serif;
}
.custom-links {
  background-color: #000000;
}
#avatar {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar" style="background-color:red;">
  <img id="avatar" src="http://i1380.photobucket.com/albums/ah161/joanwatson/138_zps4tytysv0.png" />
  <div class="pages">
    <a href="#" class="page-arrow">«</a>
    <p class="dots">
      .&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;.
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="page-arrow">»</a>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-links">
    I should size with the image
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know how I might fix this?

Comment: We can't ignore the `{}` as they need to be gone to make a working code snippet, so please fix that and update with a code snippet that does work and reproduce the issue

Comment: @LGSon So sorry—I've updated the code now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may use `display` table properties so it expand with the longest content.

`max` and `min-width` should be applied to children since it won't be avalaible with the `display:table` property on the `.sidebar` container.

```css
body {
  color:#ffffff;
}
.sidebar {
    /* position: fixed; snippet purpose */
  display:table;
    top:179px;
    left:100px;
  width:10px;/* dmo set at 10px but could be 0 or 100px */
}

.pages {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:-4px;
    border-left: 1px solid #E2C4FF;
    border-right: 1px solid #E2C4FF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E2C4FF;
    text-align:center;
}

.dots {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -70%);
    color:{color:Link Color Type 1};
    font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}

.custom-links {
    background-color:#000000;
}

#avatar, .custom-links {
    min-width:100px;
    max-width:120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar" style="background-color:red;">
    <img id="avatar" src="http://i1380.photobucket.com/albums/ah161/joanwatson/138_zps4tytysv0.png"/>
    <div class="pages">
        <a href="#" class="page-arrow">«</a>
   <p class="dots">
   .&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;.
   </p>
        <a href="#" class="page-arrow">»</a>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-links">
    I should size with the image
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `max-width`

```css
body {
  color:#ffffff;
}
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top:17px;
    left:100px;
    min-width:100px;
}
.pages {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:-4px;
    border-left: 1px solid #E2C4FF;
    border-right: 1px solid #E2C4FF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E2C4FF;
    text-align:center;
}
.dots {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -70%);
    color:lime;
    font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}
.custom-links {
    background-color:#000000;
}
#avatar {
    min-width:100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar" style="background-color:red;">
  <img id="avatar" src="http://i1380.photobucket.com/albums/ah161/joanwatson/138_zps4tytysv0.png" />
  <div class="pages">
    <a href="#" class="page-arrow">«</a>
    <p class="dots">
      .&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;.
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="page-arrow">»</a>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-links">
    I should size with the image
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are using a small image (`100px`) which is smaller than `120px` set for `max-width`

so you can:

- use a image no smaller than `120px`

or

- use `display:table` in `.sidebar`

**NOTE**: don't use inline styles, use CSS instead

```css
body {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  /* top: 179px; - removed for demo*/
  left: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 120px;
  background-color:red
}
.pages {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  border:  solid #E2C4FF;
  border-width:0 1px 1px;
  text-align: center
}
img {
  display: block
}
.dots {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -70%);
  color:white;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}
.custom-links {
  background-color: #000;
}
#avatar {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <img id="avatar" src="//lorempixel.com/200/200" />
  <div class="pages">
    <a href="#" class="page-arrow">«</a>
    <p class="dots">
      .&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;.&nbsp;&nbsp;.
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="page-arrow">»</a>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-links">
    I should size with the image
  </div>
</div>
```